# Auto extract strings to defines

Tags: php, string, echo

I just inherited a website written in PHP to internationalize it... The problem is the code is not consistent. It has some functions that have strings inside echo and another pieces and in another functions the php is closed and html is presented the right way.

I was looking for a tool that could easy my job as much as possible. Retrieving as much strings as it could and defining (through defines) in another file.

I though about creating a script with regex functions to achieve this but if there was anything out there... I looked but couldn't find. Maybe I'm using wrong terms as I'm not English native.

Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Comment: regex sounds pretty scary, AST makes more sense.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer. can you provide more details please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to using `gettext` for I18N, then you can use `xgettext`: http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/gettext/xgettext-Invocation.html

Here is a tutorial detailing how you can use it in PHP: http://www.phpdig.net/ref/rn26.html

Comment: "Note that xgettext was designed for parsing C and C++ files, and ignores single-quoted strings." This means that something like echo 'hello'; will not be catched by xgettext right?

Comment: I think that article was written quite some time ago. xgettext supports PHP as a language and single quoted strings should be parsed (just pass `--language=PHP` instead of `--c++`). Read xgettext's man page (first link) for more info.